# Flyway can't find Spring Java migrations on the classpath when using Ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath, flyway

I have Flyway set up in my project with the following directory layout (excluding irrelevant directories):

```
$ tree database
database
├── lib
│   ├── flyway-ant-2.0.1.jar
│   ├── flyway-core-2.0.1.jar
│   ├── migrate.jar
│   ├── spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
│   └── spring-jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
└── updates
    ├── java
    │   └── database
    │       └── migrate
    │           └── V1_0__create_posts.java
    └── sql
        └── V1_1__create_users.sql
```

And the relevant part of build.xml (flyway.url and flyway.driver are set in a properties file not included here---Flyway has no problem talking to the database):

```xml
<target name="path">
    <path id="migrate.build.path">
        <fileset dir="database/lib">
            <include name="flyway-*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="database/lib">
            <include name="spring-*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <path id="flyway.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="database/lib">
            <include name="flyway-*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <path id="flyway.classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="h2-*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="database/lib" includes="migrate.jar"/>
    </path>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="path">
    <mkdir dir="build"/>
    <javac srcdir="database/updates/java" destdir="build" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="migrate.build.path"/>
    <copy todir="build">
        <fileset dir="database/updates" excludes="**/*.java"/>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="database/lib/migrate.jar" basedir="build" includes="sql/**,database/migrate/**"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="compile,path">
    <!-- imported tasks -->
    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant" resource="com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="flyway.lib.path"/>

    <property name="flyway.locations" value="sql,database.migrate"/>
</target>

<!-- flyway tasks -->
<target name="db:clean" depends="init">
    <flyway:clean/>
</target>
<target name="db:init" depends="init">
    <flyway:init/>
</target>
<target name="db:migrate" depends="init">
    <flyway:migrate/>
</target>
<target name="db:validate" depends="init">
    <flyway:validate/>
</target>
<target name="db:info" depends="init">
    <flyway:info/>
</target>
<target name="db:status" depends="init,db:info"/>
<target name="db:repair" depends="init">
    <flyway:repair/>
</target>
```

Here is the layout of the migrations JAR created in the compile target:

```
$ unzip -l database/lib/migrate.jar 
Archive:  database/lib/migrate.jar
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  01-14-13 16:27   META-INF/
      103  01-14-13 16:27   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  01-14-13 16:21   database/
        0  01-14-13 16:27   database/migrate/
        0  01-14-13 16:27   sql/
      538  01-14-13 16:27   database/migrate/V1_0__create_posts.class
        0  01-14-13 16:27   sql/V1_1__create_users.sql
 --------                   -------
      641                   7 files
```

And here is the output from `flyway:info`:

```
[flyway:info] +-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
[flyway:info] | Version     | Description            | Installed on        | State   |
[flyway:info] +-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
[flyway:info] | 0           | << Flyway Init >>      | 2013-01-14 14:14:09 | Missing |
[flyway:info] | 1.1         | create users           |                     | Pending |
[flyway:info] +-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Flyway is not discovering the .class files. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:** If anyone knows of a working example of Flyway set up with Ant (no Maven, no Ivy), it would be much appreciated.

---

### Update

It turns out Flyway will find `JdbcMigration` classes, but not `SpringJdbcMigration`.

This migration is successfully loaded:

```
/* database/updates/java/database/migrate/V1_0__create_posts.java */
import com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class V1_0__create_posts implements JdbcMigration {
    public void migrate(Connection conn) throws Exception {
        conn.createStatement().execute(
            "create table posts (id integer primary key, title varchar(255), body text)"
        );
    }
}
```

But this one is skipped:

```java
/* database/updates/java/database/migrate/V1_0__create_posts.java */
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.spring.SpringJdbcMigration;

public class V1_0__create_posts implements SpringJdbcMigration {
    public void migrate(JdbcTemplate template) throws Exception {
        template.execute(
            "create table posts (id integer primary key, title varchar(255), body text)"
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the Ant debug output when using a `SpringJdbcMigration`:

```
[antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant] Could not load definitions from resource com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.                  [4/873]
[flyway:info] Database: H2 1.2
[flyway:info] DDL Transactions Supported: false
[flyway:info] Schema: PUBLIC
[flyway:info] No metadata table upgrade necessary
[flyway:info] Spring Jdbc available: false
[flyway:info] Scanning for resources at 'database/migrate' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
[flyway:info] Scanning URL: jar:file:.../flyway-sample/database/lib/migrate.jar!/database/migrate
[flyway:info] JBoss VFS v2 available: false
[flyway:info] Filtering out resource: database/migrate/ (filename: )
[flyway:info] Filtering out resource: database/migrate/V1_0__create_posts.class (filename: V1_0__create_posts.class)
[flyway:info] Scanning for classes at 'database/migrate' (Implementing: 'com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
[flyway:info] Scanning URL: jar:file:.../flyway-sample/database/lib/migrate.jar!/database/migrate
[flyway:info] Filtering out resource: database/migrate/ (filename: )
[flyway:info] Scanning for resources at 'db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
[flyway:info] Unable to determine URL for classpath location: db/migration (ClassLoader: AntClassLoader[.../flyway-sample/lib/h2-1.2.135.jar:.../flyway-sample/database/lib/migrate.jar])
[flyway:info] Scanning for classes at 'db/migration' (Implementing: 'com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
[flyway:info] Unable to determine URL for classpath location: db/migration (ClassLoader: AntClassLoader[.../flyway-sample/lib/h2-1.2.135.jar:.../flyway-sample/database/lib/migrate.jar])
[flyway:info] Scanning for resources at 'sql' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
[flyway:info] Scanning URL: jar:file:.../flyway-sample/database/lib/migrate.jar!/sql
[flyway:info] Filtering out resource: sql/ (filename: )
[flyway:info] Found resource: sql/V1_1__create_users.sql
[flyway:info] Scanning for classes at 'sql' (Implementing: 'com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
[flyway:info] Scanning URL: jar:file:.../flyway-sample/database/lib/migrate.jar!/sql
[flyway:info] Filtering out resource: sql/ (filename: )
[flyway:info] Filtering out resource: sql/V1_1__create_users.sql (filename: V1_1__create_users.sql)
[flyway:info] +-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
[flyway:info] | Version     | Description            | Installed on        | State   |
[flyway:info] +-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
[flyway:info] | 0           | << Flyway Init >>      | 2013-01-14 14:14:09 | Missing |
[flyway:info] | 1.1         | create users           |                     | Pending |
[flyway:info] +-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have all the Spring JDBC migration dependencies.

I downloaded [the latest Flyway (2.0.3) with Ant & Spring dependencies](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/downloads/detail?name=flyway-ant-2.0.3-dist-with-spring.zip&can=2&q=), added the new JARs to the classpath, and the Spring JDBC migrations are now found by Flyway.

Answer (score 2):

The **Java migrations** must be **compiled** first. (Flyway looks for .class files)

I've updated [the docs](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/ant/) to make this clearer.

Comment: I just updated the question with details of how I tried compiling the migrations first. Still no luck...

Comment: I've added a second update with details of how I compiled the Java classes and added them along with the SQL files to the classpath. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Adam, please collapse all your question updates to only show the latest situation (build file, directory layout, flyway version)

Comment: Adam, it is very hard to follow if you don't include the values of the ant variables, the Flyway call and the Flyway version. Please update. Also what does updates/<sql migrations> mean?

Comment: I've expanded any property references to their values, and included the flyway task definitions. Also added a clearer directory layout and noted that the only flyway properties set other than flyway.locations are flyway.driver and flyway.url, and database connection is not an issue.

Comment: Somehow I don't understand why the the copy fileset to /build is <fileset dir="database/updates" excludes="**/*.java"/> and not database/updates/java. Are you sure the migrate.jar contents are correct?

Comment: The javac task takes care of the .java files, outputting the classes to /build. The copy task then copies the SQL files into /build, and then the whole directory is packaged into a JAR. (I based this approach on the build.xml file in the flyway-sample app in the code.)

Comment: Could you also post the source of your java migration and a debug output of the ant run?

Comment: Hi Axel, seeing the debug output (which I didn't know existed, thanks), put me on the right track to finding the problem. I'd be happy to upvote/accept your answer if you'd like to update it to address the question. Cheers.

Comment: No worries, what matters is that you could solve your problem :-)